# Get size of mysqldump file before dumping

Tags: mysql, windows, filesize

I would like to make sure there is enough available disk space on Windows before dumping the database.

Is there a way to determine the size of a mysqldump file before executing the command on Windows?

I compared the size difference between the folder containing the .idb files and the dump.sql file. However, at least due to the encryption of the idb files, its folder is 20 times larger than dump.sql.

Thank you

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37159/how-can-i-determine-the-size-of-a-dump-file-prior-to-dumping

Answer (score 1):

There is no precise way to know the size of the dump file in advance.

The dump file includes the size of data, but not indexes. So you can get a rough estimate by viewing:

```
SELECT SUM(data_length) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE ... conditions to select the tables you want to dump ...
```

That is, omit the `index_length` and `data_free` from the sum, because the dump does not include them. The indexes are defined by CREATE TABLE statements in the dump file, but the content of the indexes is not included.

That gives only an estimate, not a precise measurement, because the text representation of data in a dump file may be different from the storage of some columns. That depends on the data types.

The only way to get a precise measure is to dump the data and see how large it is.

You could dump a 10% sample of the data, and get a small dump file:

```
mysqldump ...options... --where="RAND() < 0.10" > dump.sql
```

Then multiply the size of that small dump file by 10 to estimate the size of the full dump

You may also choose a different sample size, but if the data sample is too small, then the size of the CREATE TABLE statements and other overhead in the file will be counted disproportionately, and your estimate will be inaccurate.

Comment: The dump files only contain data. Since I know the size of the folder containing the schema, can I just subtract the schema size from the total size of the folder once populated with data to get a rough estimate of it's size? And maybe allow an extra GB for incidentals.  Could this approach possibly work?

Comment: No, InnoDB tablespace files store both data and indexes, mixed together. But dumps  only include data, not indexes. Even if the tables don't have any secondary indexes, InnoDB tables are themselves stored as clustered indexes, so there's always some nonterminal nodes in the B-trees that are not represented in the dump file. Also the tablespace files are usually partly fragmented internally, occupying more space on disk than the data they store.

Comment: Thank you Bill, I will test your approaches once I get the installer completed and MySQL is up and running again.